# Ansible - tower_host bulk delete host from inventories

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

I would like to remove a host from all the inventories it is part of.
I tried something like this, but that does not work:

```
--- 
- hosts: [MYHOST]
  tasks: 
  - name: "Test deletion"
    tower_host:
      name: "{{ vm_hostname }}"
      inventory: 
        - "RedHat"
        - "RedHat-Hors-Prod"
        - "RedHat-Prod"
      state: absent
...
```

Is this possible without create 3 differents tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by using a loop:

```
--- 
- hosts: pransibleapp
  tasks: 
  - name: "Test deletion"
    tower_host:
      name: "{{ vm_hostname }}"
      inventory: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
      .
      .
    loop:
      - "RedHat"
      - "RedHat-Hors-Prod"
      - "RedHat-Prod"
```

Doc : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list